# ways of picking four balls from a sack containing 3red balls, 3white balls, 3blue ball

Tags: combinatorics

What is the formula to solve these kind of problems.

Q. what are different ways of picking four balls from a sack containing 3red balls, 3white balls, 3blue balls. All the four balls are picked at once

Comment: There are many ways to go through this question - have you tried anything? Else I may close this.

Comment: Surely you can do this example by hand.  All you want are triples of non-negative integers $\{r,w,b\}$ which are each $≤3$ and which sum to $4$. Without the max constraint ($3$ here) this can be done in general with [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  With the max constraint, I think it's best to use generating functions, as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620640/stars-and-bars-with-restriction-of-size-between-bars-via-generating-functions)

Comment: Actually I want a generalization for this problem as I will be using that to write a computer program