# Combination and Permutation S= {A,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D,D,E,E,E,E,E}.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, multisets

**S**= {A,B,B,C,C,C,D,D,D,D,E,E,E,E,E}.

If I choose n element from **S**, how many possible combination (unordered) and permutation (ordered) are possible (without using decision tree or counting)? What is your thought process and the concept/trick used?

Example for n=2, 
There are 14 possible combination (unordered) subset. (if I didn't miss something..)
{A,B},{A,C},{A,D},{A,E},{B,B},{B,C},{B,D},{B,E},{C,C},{C,D},{C,E},{D,D},{D,E},{E,E}
and there are 24 possible permutation.

if general n isn't feasible. how about n=7 and n=15 (all) ?

Comment: What is **our** thought process and the concept/trick used? What's yours???

Answer (score 1):

Hint regarding the number of combinations: write the generating function. It is very well explained here: [Combinations of colored balls.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622658/combinations-of-colored-balls)