# Working out number of rearrangements/combinations of letters

Tags: combinatorics

Hi there so say there are 2 green hats (G) and 3 blue hats (B) and 3 are selected at random. How can I work out the number of different possible combinations? I.e.

BBB
BBG
BGG
GBB
GGB
GBG
BGB

I know the answers 7 having looked it up for this questions but was hoping someone might have a formula for working this out?

Thanks

Comment: If you were picking 3 hats from an endless supply of green and blue hats, the formula would be $2\times 2\times 2=8$ (two choices per hat). The trick here is that GGG is impossible since there are only two green hats, so the actual answer is $8-1=7$.

Comment: The number of combinations can be found using the [generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622658/combinations-of-colored-balls). The number of permutations of these combinations is a tougher task.