# How to expand this generating function

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions, formal-power-series

I am new to generating functions / power series and I am struggling with expanding following generating function:
$$F(x)=\frac{(x^2-x^{10})(1-x^{10})^3}{(1-x)^4}$$
I tried to pattern my solution on [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1935071/249955) and expand generating function in the same way, so i rewrote $F(x)$ as:
$$F(x)=\frac{x^2(1-x^8)(1-x^{10})^3}{(1-x)^4}$$
and in order to obtain coefficient at $x^{20}$ I tried to calculate:
$${(20-2)+3 \choose 3}-{(20-2)-8+3 \choose 3}-{(20-2)-10+3 \choose 3} \cdot 3$$
The result of this is $549$ which is smaller by $3$ than proper solution which is $552$. I don't know what I did wrong. In fact, I don't understand this method of expanding coefficients so if you could provide the name of this technique or some resources to read about I would be thankful. I mean, I see the pattern this technique follows, but I don't see why it works.

This generating function gives solution to one problem that I solved first in purely combinatoric way. My calculations were nearly identical to these presented above, but I had to exclude intersection of two sets which was of size $3$. So I understand that there should be $+3$ term in solution above, but I don't know where it would come from in case of expanding generating function.

Answer (score 2):

Using [negative binomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html),

\begin{align}
F(x) &= x^2(1-x^8)(1-3x^{10}+3x^{20}-x^{30})(1-x)^{-4}\\
&= x^2(1-x^8)(1-3x^{10}+3x^{20}-x^{30})\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{4+k-1}{k} x^k\\
&= (x^2-x^{10})(1-3x^{10}+3x^{20}-x^{30})\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{3+k}{k} x^k\\
&= (x^2-3x^{12}-x^{10}+\color{blue}{3x^{20}}+p(x))\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{3+k}{3} x^k\\
\end{align}

where $p(x)$ are higher order terms that are not interesting for the question.

Hence

$$\binom{18+3}{3}-3\binom{11}{3}-\binom{13}{3}+3\binom{3}{3}$$

I suspect you left out the case where we let $k=0$.

Comment: I misunderstood the process of expanding generating function. Looking at the example I linked to, I didn't realize it's author skipped some part of calculations and just gave the final result. This is why I was confused. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you missed one term. Notice that
$$(1-x^8)(1-x^{10})^3=(1-x^8)(1-3x^{10}+O(x^{20}))=1-x^8-3x^{10}+3x^{18}+o(x^{18}).$$
Hence
\begin{align}
[x^{20}]\frac{x^2(1-x^8)(1-x^{10})^3}{(1-x)^4}
&=[x^{18}]\frac{1-x^8-3x^{10}+3x^{18}+o(x^{18})}{(1-x)^4}\\
&=[x^{18}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}-[x^{10}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}-[x^{8}]\frac{3}{(1-x)^4}+[x^{0}]\frac{3}{(1-x)^4}\\
&=\binom{18+3}{3}-\binom{10+3}{3}-3\binom{8+3}{3}+3=552.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I missed one term because I wrongly deduced the pattern of expanding generating functions. So if there was a term in numerator like (1+x)^123 we would have to calculate it? I thought there is some way to avoid exponentiation.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question, please?

Comment: I mean, we had to expand numerator and then split function into partial fractions. In my situation there was a value (1+x^10)^3 so it was not hard to expand it. But if the exponent was e.g. 123 we would have a lot of work to do. So I wondered if there is a technique which lets avoid this time-consuming calculation.

Comment: No, it suffices to consider $(1-x^{10})^{123}=1-123x^{10}+O(x^{20})$