# Numbers with constant digit-sum in increasing order

Tags: combinatorics

For base $b = 10$, I want to list all numbers with $d$ digits (no leading zeros) and digit sum $x$, in increasing order.

For example for $d = 6$ and $x = 40$ we would get:

139999, 
148999,
149899,
149989,
149998,
157999,
158899,
158989,
158998,
159799,
159889,
159898,
159979,
159988,
159997,
166999,
167899,
167989,
167998,
168799,
168889,
168898,
168979,
168988,
168997,
169699,
169789,
169798,
169879,
169888,
169897,
169969,
169978,
169987,
169996,
175999,
176899,
176989,
176998,
177799,
177889,
177898,
177979,
177988,
177997,
178699,
178789,
178798,
178879,
178888,
178897,
178969,
178978,
178987,
178996,
179599,
179689,
179698,
179779,
179788,
179797,
179869,
179878,
179887,
179896,
179959,
179968,
179977,
179986,
179995,
184999,
185899,
185989,
185998,
186799,
186889,
186898,
186979,
186988,
186997,
187699,
187789,
187798,
187879,
187888,
187897,
187969,
187978,
187987,
187996,
188599,
188689,
188698,
188779,
188788,
188797,
188869,
188878,
188887,
188896,
188959,
188968,
188977,
188986,
188995,
189499,
189589,
189598,
189679,
189688, ...

Now, using the [generalized stars-bars problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded) creating a program, which produces an unordered list is easy. But for large $d$ and $x \rightarrow d \cdot b/2$, the list gets huge, so sorting it needs lots of RAM and it gets pretty slow.

I suspect (hope) there exists a ready-made algorithm, that for a number $n$ gives the nearest number $n'$, so that $n'$ has the same digit sum as $n$. Could you give me a hint?

---

**EDIT:** This is my solution in Python so far. The function returns the next integer with the same digit sum. I tested it for quite a huge range of numbers. But I don't know if it is correct. If you find an error, please let me know.

```
def next_same_xsum(x):
    BASE = 10
    t = 1
    u = 1
    while x % (u * BASE) == 0:
        u *= BASE
    if u > 1:
        y = next_same_xsum(x // u)
        w = 1

        while x // u // (w * BASE) < y // (w * BASE):
            w *= BASE
        s = y % w
        return s + (y - s) * u
    while x // (t * BASE * BASE) < (x + BASE - 1) // (t * BASE * BASE):
        t *= BASE

    if t > 1:
        z = next_same_xsum(x // t)
        r = BASE - x % BASE - 1
        return t - 1 + (z - r) * t

    return x + BASE - 1
```

Comment: how about using a recursive function. split the number as a digit (b) followed by a (d - 1) digit number whose sum of digits must be (x - b) allowing 0

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm to find the next number up. We need the following notation:
use (d,x) for a d-digit number with digit sum = x
(d,x,M) is the largest (d,x) and (d,x,m) is the smallest (d,x)

e.g. 187987 is a (6,40),  (2,15,M)=96 and (2,15,m)=69

Suppose we want the next number after 187987. We start with the last two digits:87
it is not maximal so we add 9 to 87 to get the next number: 187996
now the last three digit number 996 is a (3,24,M) in this case add 1 to the previous digit  so the 7 becomes an 8. The next number is 188 followed by (3,23,m) that is 188599

Comment: an additional problem are the numbers with trailing zeros.

Comment: 3700 is a (4,10) in which 700 is (3,7,M) so the next step would be to add 1 to the 3 and fill in the remaining with (3,6,m) (here 0 is allowed) to get the next number: 4006