# Integer solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots a_n = N$, where $l_i \leq a_i \leq r_i$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinatorial-number-theory, analytic-combinatorics

> Given $l_1, l_2, l_3, \ldots, l_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $r_1, r_2, r_3, \ldots, r_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and an integer $N$, find a general formula to calculate the number of ways that $N$ can be written as the sum $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \ldots+ a_n$, where $a_i$ is an integer such that $l_i \leq a_i \leq r_i$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

I am newbie in combinatorics. I also know the stars and bars theorem. But I dont know how to solve this.
I can solve if only it is said $l_i \leq a_i$ But cant find a way to figure out how to handle $a_i \leq r_i$

Comment: No answer yet :'(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extended stars-and-bars problem(where the upper limit of the variable is bounded)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded)

Answer (score 1):

Does this count as a formula you are searching for:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi\text{i}}\,\oint_\gamma\,\frac{1}{z^{N+1}}
\,\prod_{j=1}^n\,\left(\frac{z^{r_j+1}-z^{l_j}}{z-1}\right)\,\text{d}z\,?$$
Here, $\gamma$ is the positively oriented curve along the unit circle $\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,|z|=1\big\}$.

---

Alternatively, we look at the generating function
$$f(x):=\prod_{j=1}^n\,\frac{x^{l_j}-x^{r_j+1}}{1-x}=\frac{x^{l}}{(1-x)^n}\,\prod_{j=1}^n\,\left(1-x^{k_j}\right)=\frac{x^l}{(1-x)^n}\,\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}\,(-1)^{|S|}\,x^{\sum_{j\in S}\,k_j}\,\,,$$
where $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $l:=\sum_{j=1}^n\,l_j$, and $k_j:=r_j-l_j+1$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.  That is,
$$f(x)=x^l\,\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\,\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}\,x^m\right)\,\left(\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}\,(-1)^{|S|}\,x^{\sum_{j\in S}\,k_j}\right)\,,$$
so
$$f(x)=x^l\,\sum_{m=0}^\infty\,x^m\,\sum_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{\sum_{j\in S}\,k_j\leq m}}}\,(-1)^{|S|}\,\binom{n+m-1-\sum_{j\in S}\,k_j}{n-1}\,.$$
The required answer will be the coefficient of $x^N$ in $f(x)$, for $N\geq \sum_{j=1}^n\,l_j$, and the answer is
$$\small \sum_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{\sum_{j\in S}\,k_j\leq N-l}}}\,(-1)^{|S|}\,\binom{n+N-l-1-\sum_{j\in S}\,k_j}{n-1}=\sum_{\substack{{S\subseteq[n]}\\{\sum_{j\in S}\,r_j\leq N-|S|}}}\,(-1)^{|S|}\,\binom{n+N-|S|-1-\sum_{j\in S}\,r_j}{n-1}\,.$$
An argument using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion should yield the same formula.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce each range to $0$ to $r_i - l_i$ by defining $u_i = a_i - l_i$, then the sum to get is just $N' = N - \sum_{1 \le i \le n} l_i$. Then you have the problem to divide $N'$ stars into $n$ groups by $n - 1$ bars like  "$**||*|***$" (here $N'= 5, n = 4$, the example solution is $u_1 = 2, u_2 = 0, u_3 = 1, u_4 = 3$). That is the same as the number of ways to string up $N'$ stars and $n - 1$ bars, which is just:

$$
\binom{N' + n - 1}{n - 1}
  = \binom{N - \sum l_i + n - 1}{n - 1}
$$

This is the [stars and bars argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

But this assumes no $a_i$ is limited, need to take the limits into account. This can be done by [inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle): Compute how many solutions are with at least $u_1 > r_1 - l_1$, and so on. A veritable mess, true. Not hard, just messy.