# How to find the coefficients of the $k$-th term of $\left(\frac{x^n - 1}{x - 1}\right)^m$ for arbitrary $k$, $m$, and $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find an equation for finding the coefficient of the $k$th term of the expansion of $\left(\frac{x^n - 1}{x - 1}\right)^m$ for any $n$, $m$, and $k$.

So, far I've managed to find [A277950](https://oeis.org/A277950) the terms for $m = 5$. I however have not been able to figure out what $k$ is in their formula for the sequence, and I can't find a way to generalize it for $m \neq 5$.

I have similarly written a python program to find the coefficients, which works by looping through the integers in $[1, n]$, $m$ times and then counting the number of times each number appears. Printing the number of time each number appears in order yields the coefficients of the expansion. I have no idea why this is working, but for every set of numbers I've tried it has worked correctly.

Comment: $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1)$ So now you can use multinomial theorem to find coefficients..Note that you can't use $x=1$

Comment: @user35508, I've never used the multinomial theorem and I'm not understanding the Wikipedia page, could you post a short explanation?

Comment: Well..the multinomial theorem works just like the binomial theorem....Let's say you have three terms like $(a+b+c)^n$ So...first what you can do is write...all possible combinations of $a^kb^jc^l$ such that $k+j+l=n$...Now if you use the multinomial coefficient (generalization of binomial coefficient) you can find the coefficients $n \choose {k,j,l}$ ..So,you see this can be generalized further for more terms and you get your expansion....

Comment: But this question is simpler...as all the terms are $x^i$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extended stars-and-bars problem(where the upper limit of the variable is bounded)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^m=\binom{m}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^k]\left(\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\right)^m
> &=[x^k](1-x^n)^m\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-m}{j}(-x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m+j-1}{j}x^j\sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}(-1)^lx^{nl}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{m+j-1}{j}[x^{k-j}]\sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}(-1)^lx^{nl}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{m+j-1}{j}[x^j]\sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}(-1)^lx^{nl}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor k/n\right\rfloor}\binom{m+k-nj-1}{k-nj}
> [x^{nj}]\sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}(-1)^lx^{nl}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\left\{\left\lfloor k/n\right\rfloor,m\right\}}\binom{m+k-nj-1}{k-nj}
> \binom{m}{j}(-1)^j\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* with $\alpha=-m$.
- In (2) we expand the binomial $(1-x)^m$ and use the binomial identity

\begin{align*}
\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
\end{align*}

- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule
  $$[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$$ We also set the upper limit of the series to $k$ since the exponent of $x^{k-j}$ is non-negative.
- In (4) we exchange the order of summation of the outer sum by replacing $j\rightarrow k-j$.
- In (5) we select multiples of $n$ of the index $j$ since we have multiples of $n$ in the exponent $x^{nl}$ in the inner sum.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $[x^{nj}]$ in the inner sum by setting $l=j$.

Comment: Amazing...Too advanced for me.

Answer (score 1):

As user35508 remarked, $(x^{n}-1)(x-1) = 1+x+\cdots +x^{n-1}$. Now, as we raise it to the $m$-th power, we need to open brackets. How many times $x^k$ appears? Each factor will contribute $x^i$ for some $i$ exactly once, so the coefficients of $x^k$ equals to the number of solutions to the equation 
$$
X_1 + \cdots + X_m = k
$$ 
with $0\leq X_i\leq n-1$. This number can be explicitly expressed in terms of binomial coefficients. For example, if $n-1\geq k$ it is the same as unordered samples with replacement, so the $k$-th coefficient equals $\binom{m+k-1}{k}$.

What happens when $n-1<k$, I leave it for you to solve...

Comment: The case $k<n$ is really just the tip of the iceberg for this problem; you are basically just ignoring the numerators $x^n-1$ altogether (replacing them by$~1$). In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/554237) to a duplicate question I discuss the complications of taking into account the numerator.

Comment: I upvoted your answer.