# Candy bar combinations

Tags: combinatorics

A local mart sells 6 kinds of candy bar. You want to buy 15 candy bars. How many possibilities are there if you want more than 5 bars of any one of the kinds?

Is there any hint to solve this questions?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using [Stars and Bars combinatorial theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). See also [extended stars-and-bars problem(where the upper limit of the variable is bounded)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded)

Let $x_i$ be the number of bars of kind $i$ with $i=1,\dots,6$. Note that there are at most $2$ kinds of candy bar with more than $5$ bars (because $3\cdot 6>15$).

Case 1:  $\binom{6}1$ ways to choose a kind and, by [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two),  $\binom{14}{5}$ non-negative integer solutions of 
$$y_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=15-6=9$$
with $y_1=x_1-6$.

Case 2:  $\binom{6}2$ ways to choose the two kinds and, by [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two), $\binom{8}{5}$ non-negative integer solutions of 
$$y_1+y_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=15-6-6=3$$
with $y_1=x_1-6$, $y_2=x_2-6$.

Hence the final answer is
$$\binom{6}1\binom{14}{5}-\binom{6}2\binom{8}{5}.$$

Comment: @LingMinHao Any feedback from your side? Are you still interested in your question?