# Formula needed to calculate number of combinations for balls in buckets

Tags: combinatorics

**1. My Goal**

I want to estimate the runtime of an algorithm. To do so I need to calculate the number of combinations it has to process.

**2. Question**

The number of combinations that have to be processed is the number of unique distributions of k items into m buckets. Each bucket has its own capacity c<sub>i</sub>. The number of items k is guaranteed to fit in, i.e. 0 <= k <= sum(c<sub>i</sub>). Each item has size 1 and the items are undistinguishable (think of tennis balls as items and stacks to place them as buckets). That means a valid combination is comprised of m many numbers x<sub>i</sub>, where sum(x<sub>i</sub>) = k, and 0 <= x<sub>i</sub> <= c<sub>i</sub>.

How to calculate the number of combinations?

**3. What I Tried**

(Sorry, I'm a programmer, I start indexing at 0, but still I say "first" when I mean that there was none before.)

I'm at a loss here, because e.g. let's say the first bucket has a capacity of only 1 (c<sub>0</sub> = 1) and the second bucket is bigger, it can hold 5 items (c<sub>1</sub> = 5).
For deciding where to put the first item, I have m many choices. But depending on if I put the item into bucket 0 or bucket 1, I'm left with either m-1 or with m choices to put the second item. That makes it difficult for me to find a closed form for calculating the number of combinations.

I have an algorithm which iterates over all combinations, so it's possible for me to check the results of a formula. However, I would like to estimate the runtime in advance. Depending on my problem sizes, the runtime is usually between a second and some hours.

Comment: It might be helpful to observe that you can think of distributing k many balls, or you can equivalently think of distributing sum(c_i)-k many empty spots.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded/554237#554237) to an earlier question starts with the case in which the $c_i$ are all equal but concludes with the general case. You may find it somewhat heavy going, but see if it helps.