# Counting integer vectors of given length inside particular area/ special number compositions

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, integer-lattices

Let $v=(v_1,...,v_k)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^k$. Denote by $l(a)$ the sum of the entries of an integer vector $a$ and consider on $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^k$ the order $\leq$ defined by coordinatewise comparison, i.e. $a\leq b\Leftrightarrow \forall j\in [k]: a_j\leq b_j$. I would like to count for a fixed $m\leq l(v)$ the number of vectors $w\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^k$ s.t. $l(w)=m$ and $w\leq v$. I need a combinatorial proof/way of calculating this. I have tried a couple of things now but nothing really works out in a nice enough fashion. This is no homework or something like that. I appreciate any help and input. Thanks in advance!
This is equivalent to counting the number of number-compositions of $m$ with $k$ summands where there is an upper bound $v_i$ on the i-th summand. If that helps.

Comment: If nonnegative integer vectors instead of positive integers, your question would be [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded/) exactly. It should be clear how to translate your problem to the linked one.

Comment: Thank you very much, that confirms my apprehension that there is no closed form solution.