# Generate all stars and bars Combinations with different capacities per bar

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

I have *m* "slots" with indivual capacity *c_m*. Now I want to distribute a certain amount of integer *k* to those *m* slots without exceeding their capacity *c_m*. Such that every slot has a certain "contingent" between 0 and *c_m* and the sum of all contingents equal *k*.

Now I want to generate all the combinations, without duplicates and in a most efficient way.
Obviously I don't need to differntiate between coningents of same value. The slots have an identity though, so that their order matters.

I hope that describes my problem understandable (no homework btw).

My guess is that the best way would be to generate one trivial solution and then generate the next combination out of the previous one. I would then restrict the difference between the new and the previous
combination to at most 2, for subtracting 1 at one slot and adding 1 to another slot. From that I only need a way to identify duplicates when I'm about to generate one.
But I'm open for other ideas, too.

Comment: Look up "stars and bars" with inclusion-exclusion

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded) is a duplicate question

Comment: that goes in the right direction, thanks. Though I think the other question asks for the amount of combinations. I want to generate the combinations and I want to generate the next combination from the last one (gray-code-style). I'll edit that in the question.