# How many ways can I put m objects into n bins such that at least 1 bin has at least k objects?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In other words, how many positive integer solutions are there to

$x_1+x_2+...+x_n = m \text{ such that at least one } x\geq k$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Usually, with constraints, we can "artificially inflate" variables but in this case, we don't have a specific variable that must satisfy a constraint. I tried accounting for 1 variable at a time, then summing it up for all $x_{1-n}$, but then there's overlap.

Comment: "Positive integer" meaning each bin contains at least one object?

Comment: @aschepler yes, though the solution should look similar regardless.

Comment: If n = 3, m = 6, and k = 1, then is 1,2,3 same as 3,2,1? i.e. are all the n bins identical?

Comment: Also, are the m objects identical?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553960/177399) handles the complementary problem, where no variables are $\ge k$. This gives an answer to your question, by subtracting from the total number of solutions.

Comment: @DS Reframing the problem algebraically, it's identical objects and distinct bins

Answer (score 2):

The overlaps can be handled systematically with Inclusion-Exclusion.

Let $A_j$ be the set of those solutions where $x_j\geq k$. The quantity we're after, denote it by $f(m, n, k)$, is the size of their union. By Inclusion-Exclusion

$$f(m,n,k) = \left|\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j \right |
= \sum_{\emptyset \neq J \subset [n]} (-1)^{|J|+1} \left|\bigcap_{j\in J} A_j \right |
$$

Size of the intersection is the number of those solutions where the variables $x_j$ for $j\in J$ are at least $k$. This is given by (do the "artificial inflation")

$$
\left|\bigcap_{j\in J} A_j \right | = {m-|J|(k-1)-1 \choose n-1}.
$$

Notice that this depends only on the size of the index set $J$, so we can enumerate them by $r = |J|$. There are $n \choose r$ index sets with $|J|=r$ so we get

$$
f(m,n,k) = \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r+1} {n \choose r} {m-r(k-1)-1 \choose n-1}.
$$

Note: if $m < nk$, the sum only needs to go up to $\left\lfloor \frac{m-n}{k-1} \right\rfloor$. And if $m\geq nk$, it's guaranteed that some variable is at least $k$ and we get the total number of compositions of $m$ into $n$ parts, i.e.  $m-1 \choose n-1$.

Comment: that is a solid solution, but how do you evaluate $|J|$ in a problem, for example $m = 6$, $n = 3$ and $k = 3$?

Comment: @DS You don't need to evaluate it, as the sum simplified and you don't have to go through all the index sets.

Comment: In that example ($m=6, n=3, k=3$) you get just the term $r=1$ in the sum and it's $(-1)^2{3\choose 1}{6-2-1 \choose 2} = 9$.

Comment: Oh right, we don't need $|J|$.