# Combinatorics with percentage constraints

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, extremal-combinatorics

Say I have a $K$-component alloy system, where the $K$ components are chosen from $N$ possible metal elements ($N>K$), and the concentration of each component always ranges from $a$% to $b$% (only consider integer percentages). Two alloys are considered to be different if any metal content differs by 1%. If we don't distinguish the arrangement of the components (i.e. the order doesn't matter), what is the total number of unique alloy compositions?

For now I only know if we assume the concentrations of all compoenents are always equal, the total number of unique alloy compositions is $\displaystyle{N \choose K} = \frac{N!}{(N-K)!K!}$. But how should we take into account the percentage constraint?

Edit: To make a component considered as "exists" in the alloy, obviously it has to be at least having a percentage of 1%, thus we always have $K−1 \le a \le b \le 100−K+1$.

To give you some idea: let's say $K=3,a=2,b=98$, the first component can take a percentage equal to $2,3,\ldots,98$, but when the first component takes a percentage of 98% for example, the other two components have to both take a percentage of 1%.

Comment: You should never change a material aspect of a question after answer(s) have been received as it may invalidate posted answer(s).

Comment: @trueblueanil Sorry about that, but I don't think my edit changes the question, as it only makes sense to restrict to integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the number of ways to distribute $100$ percentage points into $N$ boxes, of which $N-K$ are empty and the remaining $K$ have between $a$ and $b$ percentage points.

First, fix $K$. We can use a generating function $G(z)$ to count the number of possibilities.

$$\tag{1}
G(z)=(z^{a}+z^{a+1}+\cdots+z^{b})^K=z^{aK}(1-z^{1-a+b})^K(1-z)^{-K}
$$

By appealing to the binomial theorem, we may write

$$\tag{2}
G(z)=z^{aK}\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^K\left(\begin{matrix}K \\ m \end{matrix}\right) (-z^{1-a+b})^{m}\right]\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\begin{matrix}-K \\ n\end{matrix}\right) (-z)^n\right]
$$

The coefficient of $z^{100}$ in the Maclaurin expansion of $G$ corresponds to the number of possibilities $\Omega_K$. By setting $aK+m(1-a+b)+n=100$ we can collapse one sum to find

$$\tag{3}
\Omega_K=\sum\limits_{m=0}^M(-1)^{aK+m(b-a)} \left(\begin{matrix}K \\ m \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}-K \\ 100-aK-m(1-a+b)\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Where $M=\operatorname{floor}(\frac{100-aK}{1-a+b})$. The total number of combinations $\Omega(N,K)$ is then $\Omega_K$ weighted by the number of ways to choose $K$ boxes out of $N$, which is again a binomial coefficient.

$$\tag{4}
\Omega(N,K)=\left(\begin{matrix}N \\ K\end{matrix}\right)\Omega_K
$$

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. I suspect that your question does not  have a nice closed form answer.

There are ${N}\choose{K}$ ways to choose the metals. Then you want to multiply that by the number of *compositions* of $100$ into $K$ parts, where the parts are restricted to the integers in $[a,b]$.

Start with the wikipedia page on [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).
For the restriction to $[a,b]$ this article linked there might help:
[Compositions of $n$ with parts in a set](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.484.5148).

Comment: Initially, I felt that the second part of the question - allocating integer weights to each alloy can be done using stars and bars. But, here we are constrained to use the positive integers $a$ through $b$,

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: To complete you can use formulas in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553960/573047), after normalizing all percentages in the composition by subtracting $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Only integer percentages are allowed to each component which must have a minimum of $a$% and maximum of $b$ %, and the %ages for the $K$ components must sum to $100$%, then the best way I see is to use generating functions.

Firstly, we put $a$ into each of the $K$ components, then $100-Ka$ are left to distribute

then  in the most rudimentary form of generating functions, we want to find the coefficient of $(100-Ka)$ in the expansion of $(1 + x + x^2 + .... + x^(b-a))^K$

and multiply by the $\binom{N}{K}$ varieties of components possible in the alloy.

**PS**

OP has remarked that the term for the base is called the "host" metal, and also clarified that  all percebtages are integers, and that they must add up to 100% So I have simplified the answer.

Comment: Restricting to integer percentages clearly makes sense. If these really are percentages they must sum to $1$. Your count does not take that into account.

Comment: @trueblueanil The concentrations of the $K$ components must sum to 1.

Comment: @trueblueanil I think there is some misunderstanding here. To be clear, there doesn't need to be a "base metal" (actually it's called a $host$ $metal$). I am studying a system called $high$-$entropy$ $alloy$, where equal or large proportions of 5 or more elements are mixed together into a single phase.

Comment: Let's say $K=2$, $a=1$, $b=99$, then for the first component we can take a percentage equal to $1,2,3…99$, and the second component fills that up to 100, so there will only be ${N\choose 2}{99\choose 1}$ distinct alloys, this is obviously not equal to ${N\choose 2}\cdot 2 \cdot(99-1+1)$

Comment: The important thing to note here is, once the concentrations of all $K-1$ components are known, the concentration of the $K$th component is automatically known.

Comment: This still doesn't seem right. Just think of when $K=3, a=2, b=98$, the first component can take a percentage equal to $2,3,...,98$, but when it takes for example 98, the other two components have to be all taking a percentage of 1.

Comment: Obviously to make a component considered as "exists" in the alloy, it has to be at least have a pecentage of 1%, thus $a \ge K-1$. This is not stated in the question but I hope this is clear.