# Number of integral solutions for $x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = n$ where $n \geq x_1 , x_2 , x_3 \geq 0$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, multinomial-theorem

I have been asked

> Integral solutions for $x_1  +  x_2  -  x_3  =  n$ where $n  \geq   x_1 , x_2 , x_3 \geq 0$.

**My approach:**

We have, $0 \leq x_3\leq n$ 
$\Rightarrow n \leq x_1 + x_2 \leq 2n$

Further, by assuming some integer $t$, for which $x_1+x_2+t = n$, we can find the number of integers for $x_1$ and $x_2$ which should take care of the corresponding values of $x_3$.

However, when I solve by taking the case of $n = 20$, my answer does not match with the given,
651.

My book solution:

> Number of solution $= \binom{n+1}{1} + \binom{n+2}{1}+\binom{n+3}{1} + \ldots + \binom{2n+1}{1} = \dfrac{(n+1)(3n+2)}{2}$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There are $(n+1)^2$ choices for $(x_1,x_2)$, and at most one choice for $x_3$ in each case, so there should be fewer than $441$ solutions.

Comment: What is your answer (for general $n$ or at least for $n=20$)?

Comment: More directly, you can take all cases of $(x_1, x_2)$, of which there are $(n+1)^2$ of them, and subtract off the complement, which is solutions to $x_1 + x_2 \leq n$ (in which case the conditions are trivial), of which there are $(n+1 \choose 2)$.

Comment: Indeed! But this complement (with $\binom{n+1}2$ solutions) is $x_1+x_2<n$, not $\le$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct (though: 1) you should have described it more explicitly, and 2) I am reluctant to name $t$ your *negative* integer: better $-i$), and your book is wrong, because it forgot the conditions $x_2,x_3\le n$.

The number of solutions is
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\left|\{(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb Z^2\mid 0\le x_1,x_2\le n\text{ and }x_1+x_2=n+i\}\right|$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^n\left|\{x_1\in\Bbb Z\mid 0\le x_1,n+i-x_1\le n\}\right|$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^n\left|\{x_1\in\Bbb Z\mid i\le x_1\le n\}\right|$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^n(n-i+1)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! My apologies as I was unable to describe my approach properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. Let $x'_3=n-x_3$. When you take $x_1+x_2-x_3=n$, and substitute $x_3\gets n-x_3'$, the result is
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3'=2n
$$
Furthermore, it is easy to see that as $x_3$ ranges over $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, so does $x_3'$. Therefore, we want to count solutions to the above where $0\le x_1,x_2,x_3'\le n$. This is a special case of [Extended stars-and-bars problem(where the upper limit of the variable is bounded)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553960). Using the methods there, we get an answer of
$$
\binom{2n+2}2-3\cdot \binom{2n-(n+1)+2}{2}
=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}2-3\cdot\frac{(n+1)n}{2}
\\\hspace{3.5cm}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}.
$$
The book's answer of $(n+1)(3n+2)/2$ is wrong.